# Ugly and slow mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to optimse this one for some time now. That is a small extract of a huge query, but that is what the query makes slow at the end. I think you get the simple table structure out of that.
Has someone an idea how to do this elegant and slim?

```
SELECT gref.gid AS gid, COUNT(o.id) AS cnt
FROM objects AS o 
RIGHT JOIN group_xref AS gx ON o.id = gx.oid 
LEFT JOIN group_xref AS gref ON o.id = gref.oid 
LEFT JOIN groups AS groups ON gref.gid = groups.id 
WHERE groups.att = 1 
GROUP BY gref.gid
```

OK here is the EXPLAIN:
http://htmlpaste.com/ff849935d884a36076f74bd934b0212bac7658e9

Comment: define slow.  It is hard to speculate on the real issue.

Comment: well if i join a few tables more i have to restart the mysql.

Comment: post the table structures

Comment: Also, can you post the results of an EXPLAIN for the query?

Comment: @Mike . . . Why are you joining to `groups_xref` twice?  What would be helpful is if you have a working version of the query and can post the explain for it.

Comment: What does the execution plan say about it ?

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to tell what the query is doing without understanding the table structure and the relationships.  I wonder if the following query is producing equivalent results and if it runs faster:

```
select gref.gid AS gid, COUNT(*) 
from group_xref gref LEFT JOIN
     groups
     ON gref.gid = groups.id 
WHERE groups.att = 1 
GROUP BY gref.gid;
```

At the very least, I think the double join to `group_xref` is unnecessary.  Here is your query without that:

```
SELECT gx.gid AS gid, COUNT(o.id) AS cnt
FROM group_xref gx left join
     objects 0
     ON o.id = gx.oid LEFT JOIN
     groups groups
     ON gx.gid = groups.id 
WHERE groups.att = 1 
GROUP BY gx.gid;
```

If I assume the linkage to objects is 1-many and all objects ids are valid, then this simplifies to:

```
SELECT gx.gid AS gid, COUNT(gx.id) AS cnt
FROM group_xref gx left join
     groups groups
     ON gx.gid = groups.id 
WHERE groups.att = 1 
GROUP BY gx.gid;
```

(which I notice is where I began).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the following indexes exist:

```
objects.id
group_xref.oid
group_xref.gid
groups.id
groups.att
```

Also, the right join with group_xref seems redundant, try:

```
SELECT gref.gid AS gid, COUNT(o.id) AS cnt
FROM objects AS o 
LEFT JOIN group_xref AS gref ON o.id = gref.oid 
LEFT JOIN groups AS groups ON gref.gid = groups.id 
WHERE groups.att = 1 
GROUP BY gref.gid
```